# Best way to implement Filewatching in my case?

Tags: c#

So, this is roughly how my C# program looks

```
Main()  
 // call to method that reads XML file and loads it into a list of structure  
 // call to method that works on the structure, manpulates data etc.  
 // call to method that starts filewatching  

Filwatching_method()  
 // if any change is detected, calls method OnChange

OnChange()  
 // Action on change
```

If `OnChange` method is called i.e. a change has been detected, I want to repeat the entire process all over again. Should I call `Main()` from `OnChange`, or is there another way that is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, this is what I think.

1. Yes, you should call your `Main` from your `OnChange` method, *if* that is in fact what you want to do (i.e., just run `Main` again).
2. But to prevent uncontrolled recursion, you should ensure that the file manipulation you're performing from *within* `Main` does not itself trigger `OnChange`. This could be by either setting a flag or temporarily removing your `Changed` handler and adding it back when you're done.

Comment: Gotcha. I'm not actually manipulating the file from within main. I only read it and then work on whats loaded onto memory and write it to another file. However, when i read the file from main(), would that cause FileWatcher to trigger OnChange method?

Comment: @xbonez: I'm honestly not sure; it *may* trigger the event if the watcher is set to watch for files' last accessed property. But you could easily test this out yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You may take a look at the [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) class which allows you to monitor and be notified of events happening on the file system like file being changed.

Comment: I have looked into that link and I got FileWatcher implemented. I'm not sure how to repeat the entire process, i.e. start my program from the beginning all over again in the occasion of a change.

Answer (score 0):

Create one [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) object, which throws several events, you can handle every event differently.